# Smashed screen on Xperia Z3, need to download data without touch capabilities

Tags: data-recovery, sony-xperia-z3

My wife accidentally smashed the screen on her Sony Xperia Z3 and the touch screen is not useable. There are colors and lines but nothing else. All of the ports on the device work just fine. However, I cannot access the phone's files with my PC because USB connection settings are currently set to charge the phone. I need to do the Data Transfer setting but am unable because of the broken touch screen. I talked to Sony support and they were no help whatsoever.

Can someone please tell me if there is a workaround? I am a tech so I will understand what you are saying even if it is complicated.
Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Also take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

I have a phone with smashed screen as well and need to recover photos and videos. Searching around I have found several places where they mention using OTG (On The Go) USB cable to hook up a mouse and keyboard, also you can possibly hook up the phone to HDTV as explained here:
http://androidforums.com/threads/broken-screen-no-backup-and-need-your-data-try-this.841614/

I am yet to try the methods described as I need to buy the necessary cables first.

Answer (score 0):

I have an otg cable and mouse and yes it will work although it will take some time to get used you should know that when you want to move you have to click and drag but other than that just a mouse should work fine